# Explanation for a proof step in lemma 3.27

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

Firstly, this question is answered here but I couldn't follow the argument in a certain part exactly.
[Proof explanation in Hatcher Algebraic Topology, Lemma 3.27](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3491626/proof-explanation-in-hatcher-algebraic-topology-lemma-3-27)
So we have a lemma from Hatcher which states,

If M is a manifold of dimension n and let $A\subset M$ be a compact subset.then:
(a)If $x\rightarrow \alpha_x$ is a section of the covering space $M_R\rightarrow M$, then there is a unique class $\alpha_A \in H_n(M|A;R)$ whose image in H_n(M|x;R) is $\alpha_x$ for all $x\in A$.
(b)$H_i(M|A;R)= 0$ for $i>n$.
Now in the proof hatchers reduces it to the case where M is $R^n$ and A is a compact convex subset of $R^n$. We clearly have isomorphisms from $H_i(R^n|A)\rightarrow H_i(R^n|x)$. However how do we conclude that there exists a unique $\alpha_A \in  H_i(R^n|A)$ that maps to $\alpha_x$ for all $x$ in A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A section over a connected set is defined by its value at a point. So we simply conisder the preimage of any $\alpha_x \in A$ in $H_n(R^n|A;R)$. Call this $\alpha_A$. We then consider the image of this $\alpha_A$ in $H_n(R^n|x;R)$ for all x in A and show this actually defines a section over A and hence must agree with the original section over A.